# Ubuntu One slow download sync speed

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, sync

I am having problems syncing my Ubuntu One files with my Ubuntu 12.04 fresh installation. Everything went well during the setup phase. Now, I am trying to sync back in my folders in my U1 account and the transfer speed is extremely slow. I am averaging a 15kb/s transfer speed. I tried uninstalling ubuntuone-client and reinstalling it. It did not fixed the problem. Right now U1 is stuck downloading a 50mb file. It is taking forever. Any ideas?

Speed Test: http://speedtest.net/result/1922664547.png
Screenshot: http://postimage.org/image/obs3f410z/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/990718).

Basically, the problem is the following:

> We are experiencing some network slowdowns because of the big demand
>   for the 12.04 release, and measures are being explored to cope with
>   it. It should go back to normal in the next few days.

As you can see, using `u1sdtool --current-transfers` in terminal will allow you to verify that this indeed is the problem (particularly, low download speed and after a while, `read bytes` resets to zero).

Hopefully, it will get back to normal soon.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe the system status webpage should reflect the same to Files. As I thought the only service being affected was Login/Authentication.