# Ubuntu One doesn't appear to be downloading?

Tags: ubuntu-one, downloads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu One slow download sync speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128019/ubuntu-one-slow-download-sync-speed)

Basically, my PC's hard drive failed, so I've now installed 12.04 on a new hard drive, and put it in.

Ubuntu One says that it has 200 files to download (although, it seems odd that it's exactly 200) and that it's currently syncing.

However, apart from the folders (and a few files in the Ubuntu One folder) none of my files appear to be downloading/downloaded. e.g. If I look in my Music folder all the folders are there, but there are no music files. In all, all the files it would have to download are about 3.2 GB. Is there any way to make it start downloading? I've tried restarting, disconnecting, but to no avail.

Thank, Jack :)

Comment: I have a similar problem

[The difference is that I see an error during instalacióión][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/128483/error-while-installing-u1